# Invalid cross-device link

Tags: nfs

I am running NAMD simulation on an 8-node cluster with one NFS-shared folder on the head node. However, the simulation sometimes stop midway, complaining "invalid cross-device link". I am not really sure whether this is caused by NAMD and/or NFS but as far as invalid cross-link is concerned, isn't it related to some kind of filesystem problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by NAMD trying to create a soft link between two different partitions (or network directories)